# Is there any more lore on Maleffluent?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, published-adventures, lore, artifacts

I'm doing a campaign in 5e and I'm going to be bringing my PC's into 'The Forgotten Terror' scenario from the Ruby of Aggarath (Dagger, not domain.) It will have my own spin on it and rules will be altered for play in 5E of course.

I just need some more information of Maleffluent. If my PC's do indeed take the axe then one of them will be cursed and I wanted to make it a big deal. They should want to get rid of it. I saw in a piece of lore that Maleffluent is a Tanar'ri demon and can be banished at the ruins of Myth Drannor where he was imprisoned to begin with, in which case I could run the Ruins of Myth Drannor Campaign and embed it in there.

If anyone has any information on Maleffluent or knows where I can find the lore it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

AFAICT, the only official mentions of Maleffluent are in the 2E modules Castle Spulzeer (TSR-9544) and The Forgotten Terror (TSR-9537). The rest appears to be [fan-made content](https://dread-on-the-horizon.obsidianportal.com/items/maleffluent). Therefore:

- bad news: you have to make it up yourself (or borrow from someone else).
- good news: you get to make it up yourself (or borrow from someone else).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know 5e rules, so I will give my answer based on 2e rules. My players did meet Maleffluent and one of them used it to defeat the elemental conjured by Chardath after defeating him inside the gem universe (The Forgotten Terror). The normal rules from 2e says a intelligent weapon causes damage to a wielder of different alignment (in this case, Maleffluent is Chaotic Evil and the pc was Lawful Neutral), but in the Forgotten Terror, page 60, in Maleffluent description, is said "...This plan will almost certainly involve coming into the possession of one of the player characters." Since the adventure is not recommended to evil groups, I assumed Maleffluent had the power to not cause damage to wielders, in order to manipulate and corrupt characters as seems intended by the authors. This PC got ridden from the item after scaping Aggarath when he was defeated by Falkovnia soldiers, using 2e optional rules for allowing characters to survive beyond 0 hp. As this is an optional rule, I allowed to this PC circunvent the statement in Castle Spulzeer, page 61, in Mallefluent description: "Only death or a 30th-level wizard can separate this weapon from the unfortunate being who picks it up." It was not my intention to make this possession a 'big deal', but you have good opportunities with the official information available, because you can let the 'only death' statement be very restrict and ensure your PCs try to find a way to free their companion without killing him, which could include divination spells and the search for a 30th-level wizard (something extremely hard to achieve in 2e, in FR at the time I remember only from The Simbul having this level, and maybe a impossible task in Ravenloft, but here you can have interesting options, as to force the PCs to negotiate with a new dark lord from a obscure island, or, why not, Vecna itself).